# Is it have or had in this question?

Tags: questions, past-simple

Is it "have" or "had" in this question? And why?

Did they get married and have a child?

Or

Did they get married and had a child?

I know statement form can be used in questions in informal speech so maybe, for this reason, the second option works.

I'm inclined to think the first option is right, with did they being omitted in the second option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is correct and the second is incorrect.  As you suggest, the word "did" (and the subject they) is omitted from the second part.

> Did they get married and (did they) have a child?

The word "have" is therefore in the bare infinitive form.